# Find picture on page by url, and put data below

Tags: javascript, image, url, element

I'm trying to figure out a way of finding a picture by its URL in a DOM, and then inserting a little form below the picture. I need help understanding the idea of finding a picture on the page by URL, and how I could place data right below the picture. It doesn't need to be anything fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Attribute equals selector.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Therefore something like:

```
$("img[src='Your URL']")
```

To then add a form you can use the Append method

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Therefore something like:

```
$("img[src='Your URL']").append("your HTML");
```

EDIT:

See JS fiddle of a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2RDJU/1/

I've actually used `after()` http://api.jquery.com/after/ rather than append as we cannot insert HTML into a img tag.

Comment: What would I put in the "your HTML" part, nothing specific, I'm just confused what should even go there.

Comment: Hi - I've edited my answer to include a working example via jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with jQuery very easily:

```
$('img:not([src="imageNameHere.png"])');
```

Just make sure you put the following line in your head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery it's quite simple:

```
$('img[src=/url/to/image]')
```

using standard JS, you're stuck with something more like

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   if (imgs.src == '/usr/to/image') {
      ...
   }
}
```